# Как получить конфигурацию не в виде строки?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, configuration

Получаю вот таким способом `_configuration["ConnectionSmtpClient:Port"]`
А как можно еще получить?

Comment: [GetValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#getvalue)

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov Спасибо